# How to find and sum n values from a determinate position of a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I've a question.

I have a list of n numbers and the list length can be 0, 6 elements or multiple of 6 (12, 18, ..., 260, ...).

I also have a counter that tell me for how many blocks of 6 numbers I have in the list.

Ex.

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

count = 1

B = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1,]

count = 2
```

What I'm trying to do is find and sum the values of the first position every 6 values incrementing the position, like:

a[0]+a[7]+a[14]+...

a[1]+a[8]+a[15]+...

I've tried to split the list in 2 sub-lists with half size but is ineffective if I have elements multiple of odd numbers.

I've also tried to create a unique for cycle that takes and sum all the required positions but ineffective if I have an unknown numbers of elements

What could be a optimal solution and how I can implement it? I'm lacking for ideas and I'm starting to have headache.

This is a test code that I've tryed to wrote:

```
//nSegnalazioni = 2 in this case because I've 2 blocks of 6 numbers
int occurencies = nSegnalazioni;
            
List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    sum.add(Integer.parseInt(importanzaEventi.get(i)+importanzaEventi.get(6+i)));
```

Comment: Your solution seems unnecessarily complicated (and wrong). Why not loop for (list length % 6) + 1, and add to sum list.get(i*6)? This is not an average as your variable name seems to indicate.

Comment: @tnw you mean like this?
for(int i=0; i<(list_length%6)+1; i++)
list.get(i*6)?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Unmitigated the output should be a list of 6 elements that contain in the first position the sum of all the first position block, in the second position the sum of all the second position of each block, in the thirth ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this, with a single iteration :
Edit : the HashMap is here just for convenience. In this case I just wanted to demonstrate the logic behind the modulo.
You could store the sum in any other fast structure like an array of int or anything else

```
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6};
    // init the map that will contains the sums
    Map<Integer, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();
    sums.put(0, 0);
    sums.put(1, 0);
    sums.put(2, 0);
    sums.put(3, 0);
    sums.put(4, 0);
    sums.put(5, 0);

    
    for(int i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        // retrieve current key : 0 -> 0,  6 -> 0, 12 -> 0, etc...
        Integer key = i % 6;
        // compute sum from old value and current array value
        int oldSum = sums.get(key);
        int newSum = oldSum + arr[i];
        // update with new value
        sums.put(key, newSum);
    }
```

HashMap has a very fast access time

Answer (score 0):

You need a second level of iteration, that iterate depending on the amount of times you have block of 6 values. Also you don't need to precise the amount of block, just use a division

```
static List<Integer> sum(List<Integer> importanzaEventi) {
    int blockSize = 6;
    if (importanzaEventi.size() % blockSize != 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    int blockCount = importanzaEventi.size() / blockSize;
    List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
        int tmpSum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < blockCount; j++) {
            tmpSum += importanzaEventi.get(i + blockSize * j);
        }
        sum.add(tmpSum);
    }
    return sum;
}

System.out.println(sum(List.of(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))); // [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
System.out.println(sum(List.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1))); // [2, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5]
System.out.println(sum(List.of(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))); // [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

Using `Streams`

```
static Collection<Integer> sum(List<Integer> importanzaEventi) {
    return IntStream.range(0, importanzaEventi.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % 6, Collectors.summingInt(importanzaEventi::get))).values();
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it you're always going to have a `6` sums. So just add the values to the summing array (results) at `index % 6`.

```
int[] v = {4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4};

List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(List.of(0,0,0,0,0,0));
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    int index = i % 6;
    results.set(index, results.get(index)+v[i]);
}
System.out.println(results);
```

prints

```
[4, 6, 5, 3, 5, 7]
```

Of course, a resulting array would be easier. Since local `int` arrays are initialized to `0's` upon creation. It doesn't get much easier than the following.

```
int[] results = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    results[i % 6] += v[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (avg.size() != 0) {
    int[] sum = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < avg.size(); j += 6) {
            sum[i] += avg.get(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, sum array will look like this

```
sum[0] = avg[0] + avg[6].... 
sum[1] = avg[1] + avg[7]....
```

and so on

I hope this is the solution you are looking for.